# How to reorder the elements of each line in a file using sed and/or awk following a dynamic format

Tags: bash, awk

I currently have a file with each line containing ordered data. For example:

```
Peter:Connor:14:40kg
George:Head:56:60kg
```

I have a listing function that takes as an argument a "format" string.
That string contains abbreviations representing each possible element of the list. In this example, the abbreviations would be:

`%N, %S, %A, %W`

Those abbreviations can be preceded or followed by any amount of characters.

I want to print the data so that it fits the received string format, replacing each abbreviation with their corresponding element in the list. For example, I might receive:

```
{%A} [%W] %S %N
```

or

```
%S|%N|%A[[%W]]
```

And I would need to reorder the data so that it fits the demanded format. Since it's an argument in the function, I have no way to know what I will receive beforehand.

```
{14} [40kg] Connor Peter
```

and for the 2nd example

```
Connor|Peter|14[[40kg]]
```

How can I use awk to do this?

Comment: wrt `I still have trouble understanding how to use them together` - you don't. sed is **only** for doing `s/old/new` (despite all the arcane language constructs only s, g, and p are actually useful) and you never need sed when you're using awk since awk can do anything sed can do. What does `I might receive` mean? Are those values like {age} strings in an input file or coming from a pipe or stored in a shell variable or something else?

Comment: I thought I could use sed and awk together because I thought I'd seen them together while searching for solutions. If awk can do everything on its own: all the better. To clarify, I have a global var containing a list of multiples entries, ordered "x, y, z" for example. I fire up a function that takes a string as an argument. That string is the format I should use to return each line of my global var.

So for example if the format string is "[a]{b}$c$",
each line of my global var should be printed as "[x]{y}$z$"

I hope that clarifies...

Comment: wrt `I thought I could use sed and awk together` - yes you can and you can also add greps and trs and cats and all sorts of other tools too but there's just no need for it. I'm sorry but the rest of your comment about the format string and a global var didn't clarify anything for me.If the answer I posted doesn't do what you want then please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements with a more descriptive example.

Comment: I have edited for future readers. But your solution was definitely acceptable for my requirements. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Please put it back the way it was because now the answers posted here make no sense wrt the completely changed question so it's now no longer of any use to anyone with with a similar problem to your new question or your original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `I might receive...` leads to you being able to pass a string with that value to awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = ":"
    tmp = fmt
    sub(/^[^[:alpha:]]+/,"",tmp)
    split(tmp,flds,/[^[:alpha:]]+/)
    gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+/,"%s",fmt)
    fmt = fmt ORS
}
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
    next
}
{ printf fmt, $(f[flds[1]]), $(f[flds[2]]), $(f[flds[3]]), $(f[flds[4]]) }

$ awk -v fmt='{age} [kilo] surname name' -f tst.awk file
{14} [40kg] Connor Peter
{56} [60kg] Head George

$ awk -v fmt='surname|name|age[[kilo]]' -f tst.awk file
Connor|Peter|14[[40kg]]
Head|George|56[[60kg]]
```

For the above to work there has to be something that names the columns  You could hard-code that in the script if you like but I added it as a header line to your CSV instead:

```
$ cat file
name:surname:age:kilo
Peter:Connor:14:40kg
George:Head:56:60kg
```

Comment: Why are the column names needed? Is there a way to do it that doesn't necessitate column names? Can't `{ printf fmt, $(f[flds[1]]), $(f[flds[2]]), $(f[flds[3]]), $(f[flds[4]]) }` be replaced with `{ printf $(f[flds[1]]), $(f[flds[2]]), $(f[flds[3]]), $(f[flds[4]]) }`?

Comment: You want to print columns based on the layout `{age} [kilo] surname name`, right? How would you know which column in your data is "age" if the columns don't have names? For the second part - try it and see.

Comment: I suppose I will :)

Comment: I am overwhelmed by your enthusiasm :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"; OFS=" "}{print "{"$3"}","["$4"]",$2,$1}' inputFile
```

gives:

```
{14} [40kg] Connor Peter
{56} [60kg] Head George
```

and

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"; OFS="|"}{print $2,$1,$3"[["$2"]]"}' inputFile
```

yields

```
Connor|Peter|14[[Connor]]
Head|George|56[[Head]]
```

Comment: Just to clarify, in the first awk command, you put everything in between apostrophes, and in the second "inputFile" is not inside the apostrophes. Is that an error?

Comment: I might also add that in this solution, the format is hard-coded.
I might have received a string like `surname&name&kilo++age` as the format to reproduce and the two solutions above wouldn't work

Comment: @GildoConte Yes, the apostrophe in the first command was misplaced. I have corrected this.